# Команда глобального поиска программы в системе

Tags: ubuntu

Как найти программу установленную в системе. Мне известно что программы по умолчанию устанавливаются в /usr. Но если есть случай когда программу установили не стандартным способом и забыли что она находится в системе то можно её как то найти, одной командой? 'надеюсь я понятно выразил свою мысль'  :)

Comment: `$ locate слово` либо `$ find / -type f -name слово`

Comment: Спасибо, закреплю как закладку в своем браузере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть еще команда `which`, она помогает найти программу, если она находится в одном из каталогов, перечисленных в переменной `$PATH`:

```
which ls
>/bin/ls
```

А так, конечно же плюсую `locate` и `find`, см. комментарий alexander barakin.